# gridview data source to datatable

Tags: asp.net

I have the following line of code that returning a null:

```
DataTable TheGridData =  (DataTable)MyGrid.DataSource;
```

What's the problem?

BTW, I'm looking to extract the datasource of a gridview, put it in this datatable, sort the datatable according to parameters and then bind the datatable back to the gridview. Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context for the line of code you share above? Where is this in your code-behind? When are you calling this? Where/when is the data actually bound to the grid?

Comment: This line is in the event handler of the sorting of the grid. The grid is initially bound with a list that's the result of a linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look this may help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridView_To_DataTable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Type of the MyGrid datasource must not be a DataTable, so you will not be able to cast it to an object of type DataTable

Comment: The initial binding of the grid is with a List that contains the result of a link query. Could this be it?

Comment: Im thinking it might be. I dont think that u can cast a List to a DataTable...but im not 100% on that